# Yii 2 Field 2 must have greater value than Field 1

Tags: php, forms, yii, widget

I've just started with Yii (2.0) and I have a problem.

I need to make sure that the Maximum Order Quantity is always equal or greater than the Minimum Order Quantity. Which means, that you can't order a minimum of 10, and maximum of 5 for example.

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

And some code:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'minimum_order_quantity')->widget(TouchSpin::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Minimum Order Quantity ...',
        'class' => 'input-lg',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'buttonup_class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
        'buttondown_class' => 'btn btn-info', 
        'buttonup_txt' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>', 
        'buttondown_txt' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i>'
    ],
]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'maximum_order_quantity')->widget(TouchSpin::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Maximum Order Quantity ...',
        'class' => 'input-lg',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'buttonup_class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
        'buttondown_class' => 'btn btn-info', 
        'buttonup_txt' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>', 
        'buttondown_txt' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i>'
    ],
]) ?>
```

This would be the _form.php.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a rule in you Model:

```
[['maximum_order_quantity'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'minimum_order_quantity', 'operator' => '>='],
```